# How add months as a x-axis to stock chart/ high charts

Tags: highcharts

I want to implement bar line graph with time scale. I implement it like this.I want to add x-axis like ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'] and I try in different ways but i couldn't able to display x-axis in this format.
jsfiddler : http://jsfiddle.net/1g3fLqao/5/

```
html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/master/highstock.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
new Highcharts.StockChart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'container'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Average Monthly Temperature and Rainfall in Tokyo'
        },
      yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°C',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        }
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mm',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
      series: [
        {
            name: 'Rainfall',
          type: 'column',
          yAxis: 1,
          data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
          tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        }
        }, {
        name: 'Temperature',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        }
        }]});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the `category` axis type in stock charts, but you can use `Highstock` source code to create simple `chart` with categories and Highstock features:

```
Highcharts.chart({
    navigator: {
        enabled: true
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    ...
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x7pusj9m/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

Comment: can I be able to add same month x-axis to below time scale

Comment: Hi @heshjse, Sorry but I do not understand, could you explain your problem more precisely?

Comment: below the graph we have bar to change the x-axis margin. currently it shows 1 jan 00:00:00.005 and 00:00:00.010. can you please tell me how change it to jan,feb,mar,... I want show months in that bar

Comment: @heshjse, You can use the `formatter` function for the navigator: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w2pux6md/

Comment: do you know how to add drop down or text field to select start month and end month? previous http://jsfiddle.net/1g3fLqao/5/ have that month selector.  After you change Highcharts.stockChart to Highcharts.chart , that month selector is not there.

Comment: You can enable the `rangeSelector` and set custom buttons and input format: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/msnapj40/, but you can also check the way without categories: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Laqtxkdf/

Comment: jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/msnapj40 take date range as 1970-01-01 how can i take date range from given data? and 1m 3m 6m 1y also not working.

Comment: @heshjse, As I said, you can set custom buttons and input format: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bonkfqjm/, but the categories do not work well with `rangeSelector` because it is intended for `datetime` axes. So the second solution (http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Laqtxkdf/) is better.